# Регистрация пользователя в приложении, использование нескольких аккаунтов

Tags: java, android

В реализации приложения появилась трудность. Мне нужно сделать систему  регистрации, но смысла уходить в бек и курить spring и делать api не нужно.  Поддержку firebase я пока реализовывать тоже не хочу, мне нужна пока что локалка.
Я вижу это так - пользователь зарегестрировался - вводит логин, пароль. Если этого логина нет в приложении - создается такой.

Затем должна создаваться таблица, для каждого пользователя,(только осваиваю SQLite) - её имя = имя пользователя. Собственно как это можно реализовать? Или есть другие пути?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас 2 вопроса в одном, засим 2 части в ответе (вообще лучше и правильнее - один вопрос на один вопрос):

1. Регистрация без бэка - довольно сомнительное предприятие с точки зрения полезности. Если всё же хотите именно так, учитывая, что при стирании данных приложения или удалении приложения все данные потеряются, то делайте. Создайте таблицу для юзеров с логином/паролем и напишите нужную логику.
2. Создавать по таблице на каждого юзера - абсолютно неправильно. У вас должна быть одна таблица на всех юзеров, где записи того или иного юзера будут определяться колонкой с ID юзера. Это называется связью `один-ко-многим`